# Having Trouble Installing Eclipse on Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

This is my first time with the macOS operating system so I could be making a common mistake easily, but I've watched multiple Youtube videos and read some articles and I haven't found an answer yet on why my Eclipse IDE isn't working. I've tried completely uninstalling Eclipse and re-downloading it and it still has the same error. The application installs correctly, but every time I try running the program it says "An error has occurred" and to check the .metadata/.log file. The problem is when I go to that directory nothing is created. I would appreciate any help from anyone who has experienced this issue before or knows how to fix it. I have both Java 9 for the JDK and JRE.

Images: [Error Message (Blocked out my name)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeKr9.png]) |
[Shows no files were created for me to check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VHI4.png)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Downgrade to Java 8 if you can.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion if you are new to OSX is to install Homebew. https://brew.sh/
It's a package manager that makes installing the software you need to get coding much faster and easier. To find out how to install a package I just google "brew install (insert name of software here)" and always find helpful results. Granted, you will have to do this from the command line. But if you are a programmer already this should be easy and, if you are learning, it's something you ought to learn how to use anyhow.

Java 9 is also pretty new (it was released in late Sept). I don't know how likely that is to be the cause, but you may want to consider using Java 8 for a while longer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll defiantly will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

> but every time I try running the program it says "An error has occurred" and to check the .metadata/.log file.

This error is due to incompatibility of previous versions of Eclipse with JDK 9. The workaround, as listed in this [Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9), is to configure Eclipse to run on Java 9 VM.

However, as of today, Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1.a is available for [download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/), which has in built support for JDK 9.

I also had jdk 9, and I installed this new version of Eclipse a few hours back, and it's working.

Comment: Thank-you for your help! I probably should've checked for compatibility, but thanks for the description so I can learn from this! Really appreciate it!